# ImportError with Sympy

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy

I'm trying to import the module sympy.physics.quantum.sho1d, but every time it results in

```
ImportError: No module named sympy.physics.quantum.sho1d
```

Is it because it isn't described in the `__init__` file? If so, what would I need to do for it to import correctly.

Comment: What code is causing the error? Seeing it might help. Also, include the full traceback.

Comment: What `sympy.__version__` do you have? I see that `sho1d` was added in the latest version, 0.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your installation is OK. `import sympy.physics.quantum.sho1d` works just fine for me.